# What if the Torah Reader for the Curses (Tochacha) is a Kohen or Levi?

Tags: torah-reading, curse, ki-tavo, bechukosai

It is (at least) the Chabad custom that the Torah Reader takes the Aliya with the curses (tochacha) in Parshat Ki Tavo and Bechukotai. The reader ascends without being called and recites the blessings before and after. (See the [Luach Colel Chabad](https://www.colelchabad.org/assets/pdfs/Elul_English.pdf)).

What happens if the Torah Reader is a Kohen or a Levi? The curses don't appear in his Aliya! And, once a Yisroel is called to the Torah, we do not call a Levi for an Aliya.

Does someone else take the Aliyah? Do we let the Levi take it, since he is not being called?

Comment: Are there any Yisraelim in the room? :)

Comment: @DoubleAA: Who can read the Torah? In this case, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Minchas Elazar ([Shu"t Minchas Elazar 1:66](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14912&st=&pgnum=167)) discusses this case, and suggests as follows:

- For Parshas Bechukosai, where the curses are closer to the beginning of the Parsha, the Baal Koreh can get Cohen, and read until after the curses.
- For Parshas Ki Savo, where the curses are closer to the end of the Parsha, they should make the earlier Aliyos shorter, and read the curses as Achron

Comment: Does Acharon mean the 8th Aliya (what is usually maftir)? If so, does that mean that there is no repeating?

Comment: @Menachem That is how I understood it

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81053

Comment: I assume "acharon" means an eighth _aliya_, preceding _kadish_ and _maftir_. Many Hasidic groups have this every week as a matter of course, though I don't know whether Munkács is one of them, and many others are not averse to it.

Comment: OK, Michoel ... what should they do if Behar / Bechotai are together? There is a general rule that the 4th aliyah should span both parshi'ot.

Answer (score 2):

I have been in a Shul where the Torah reader was a Levi and they made the curses Aliya into Acharon.

Comment: @Shmuel What Din is that? It's an explicit Mishna that permits it.

Comment: @DoubleAA IIRC, the Tzemach Tzedek said that the din in the mishna was only applicable when they had the Oleh doing the reading (And the Baal Kore reading under his breath helping him out).

Answer (score 1):

I have witnessed in Chabad Shuls where the Baal Koreh was a Cohen, that a Yisroel volunteered to take the aliyah without being called up.

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna Brura 428:17 says a Cohen can read everything from the start of בחקתי through the end of the תוכחה as a single Aliyah; there is enough left to make six more Aliyos. For כי תבוא, he suggests making an Acharon (8 Aliyos instead of 7), and giving the Cohen the extra Aliya to include the תוכחה.

(He gives some more details in the Biur Halacha, including exact stopping places and dealing with a double parsha.)

This is the same suggestion later recorded in the Minchas Elazar, cited by another answer.

[image: image of relevant section of משנה ברורה and ביאור הלכה]