# Ki Tisa with no Kohen

Tags: torah-service, levites-leviyim, parashat-ki-tisa

The first two aliyot of Ki Tisa are very long.  This is to ensure that a Levi has the aliyah about the golden calf, since his ancestors didn't participate.

Yesterday I was in a shul with no kohen.  They didn't do anything special, they just gave a Levi the first aliyah and someone else the second.  This defeats the purpose of the long aliyot.

I thought it would have made more sense to combine the first two aliyot into one super long one, and add another division later.   This way a Levi would have the part about the eigel.

Has anyone ever seen this done or a source that recommends it?

Comment: Do you have a source for the reason the first two aliyot are so long?

Comment: @Menachem no, unfortunately I don't remember

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55982/5151

Comment: These long Aliyot are a later innovation. If you aren't going to give the Egel to a Levi might as well use the 'original' breaks

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree in principle.  In practice you don't always know in advance whether or not you'll have a Kohen there.  If I were a gabbai on the spot I would have no idea where to find the original divisions.  I suspect the gabbai in this case didn't think of either your suggestion or mine (or other creative options like giving the aliyah to a chalal, which would also be difficult in practice without embarrassing him).

Comment: @heshy you can find them in scimonsters link above. A good shul rabbi should be prepared even if modern publishers have slacked off.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30735

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81083/11532