# Are there certain people that should not be called for the aliyah having the rebuke?

Tags: torah-service, rebuke-tochacha, ki-tavo, bechukosai

This coming Shabbat, in *Bechukotai* the 5th *aliyah* includes a section known as תוכחה (words of "rebuke" if we do not follow G-d's laws.)

Our shul ritual committee discussed who to give the *aliyah* to, and someone suggested the rabbi. The cantor said, "No, it's inappropriate to give it to the rabbi or the Torah reader."

I'm unaware that there is any halacha that prevents certain people from specifically getting this aliyah. (I'm not talking about people who might be barred from getting any aliyah, like an *avel* or giving this aliyah to a Cohen or Levi, as it' sthe 5th aliyah.) Are there any restrictions on who can receiv eit or any suggestions on who SHOULD receive it?

BTW my question would apply similarly to the תוכחה in כי תבוא .

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30733/what-if-the-torah-reader-for-the-curses-tochacha-is-a-kohen-or-levi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the person who is giving the *aliyot* out generally keeps this one for himself so nobody else will feel bad about having been given the *aliya*. I have also heard of this *aliya* being given to the *baal korei* or the rabbi for the same reason.

The *Mishnah Brurah* [428:17](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.428.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) brings the custom of the *gabbai* taking the *aliya* but mentions that the proper custom is for the *baal keriah* himself to take the *aliya* and mentions that since he is presumably *shomer mitzvot* he shouldn't be concerned about bad luck befalling him.

In that same section of the *Mishnah Brurah*, he mentions that in any case, if someone is called up to the Torah for the *aliya* he should go up:

> ומ"מ אם קראוהו בודאי צריך לעלות (דמי שקראוהו לעלות לס"ת ואינו עולה גורם שיתקצרו ימיו)‏

so it seems that there isn't precisely a *halakhic* problem anybody from the *shul* having the *aliya* although there are at least customary preferences.